# How Can I Create A MYSQL Database Using A Name Entered By The User

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash

I'm trying to automate the setup of new wordpress hosting clients on my webserver and each client needs it's on MYSQL DB however I cannot figure out a way to give each one a unique name by excepting input from a user

I've tried entering a default value, i.e. wordpressJohn and it worked perfect however it cannot pull in the variable from above and I'm unsure if I am doing it right or not.

```
read -p "Enter The Customer's Domain Name: " domainName   
shortenedDomainName=$domainName | cut -f1 -d"."   
sudo mysql -uroot -e "CREATE DATABASE wordpress$shortenedDomainName" 
sudo mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on wordpress$shortenedDomainName.* to 'admin_$shortenedDomainName'@'localhost' identified by 'arandompasswordhere';"
sudo mysql -uroot -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

I would expect the script to run and create a database based off of the domain name entered i.e:

```
Domain entered = howtofish.com
```

I would expect the database wordpresshowtofish to be made, the user admin_howtofish to be given full privileges to the database using a random password

However, what I get is:

```
Domain entered = howtofish.com
```

I get the database wordpress made, the user admin is given full privileges to the database using a random password

Comment: You are doing this wrong. Don't try to pass in variables to mysql, instead "prepare" your script and then execute it. I'm not sure what language you use, but if for example you use PHP then you can "prepare" the Grant's and everything using sprintf and any variables you like; then just execute it. You can even create a bash script to take arguments and do the same thing I said, possibilities are unlimited. And please try to format your questions better because it can hardly be understood... and it will get down voted and unanswered.

Comment: @JackHubbleday Welcome to SO! I fixed some typesetting for you to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the SO guide that it gave me so assumed it may print it out a bit better, my bad. I'm using a bash script

Comment: `*cough*` [sql injection](http://turnoff.us/geek/sql-injection/)/[shell injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) `*cough*`

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved it.

```
read -p "Enter The Customer's Domain Name: " domainName                                                                                                           
shortdomname=${domainName//.}                                                                                                                                     
dbname=${shortdomname}_db                                                                                                                                         
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE ${dbname};"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${dbname}.* TO 'dbadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'random';"
mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```